# SalesforceIQ API: Updating Custom Field in ListItem

Tags: api

I have a list of sales leads in SalesforceIQ.  I'm trying to use the API to update my sales leads from a CSV.  I have a custom field, call it XYZ in each of my sales leads.

I want to be able to update a given sales lead's XYZ field using the API.  Unfortunately, since it's a custom field, I'm unsure of how to do this.

It looks like ListItem objects have a fieldValues field...

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have any code you wrote in an attempt to utilize the api? If so, you should [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: @battery.cord I don't really know where to begin with uploading information in a custom field for a ListItem so I don't have any code yet :(

Comment: Try looking through the [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm) introduction page. Once you have some code working, or a solid sample of what you're trying to do, you'll get a much better response from the community.

Comment: @battery.cord This is for SalesforceIQ, so I can only use that API (I think)